# DNN Live Articles - Article published by itself

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke

On our DNN portal (version 7.3.4) we are using Live Articles module - for posting articles/news. When new article/news is published, subscribed users get notification email about that.

Few days ago we and all the subscribers have received such an email but no article/news was really published at all - last published one was half a year ago, which is correct. 
So why did we get that email notification?

I went to check Database DNN logs and found out that:

1. The article was really created - it was a generic "Welcome to Live Article".
2. I guess it was created through workflow, because there are events in table LiveArticles_Workflow about that article which indicates there were three steps taken - "Content Approval", "Content Staging" and "Direct Publishing.
3. By ModuleID I see that it was created in module that doesn't even exist in our DNN - ModuleID is way to high.

Does anybody had such an issue before? 
Is it possible that module was updated or something (but not by us) and that's why we've get such a notification?

I thank you all in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to contact the vendor? In this case it is [Mandeeps](https://www.mandeeps.com). They have a support area there, and a knowledge base that could help you.